# Gradle version catalogue - share a version between multiple toml files

Tags: gradle

Currently I do something like following:

**Toml Files**

```
// tools.versions.toml
[versions]
kotlin = "1.7.10"
gradle = "7.2.1"
maven = "2.0"
```

```
// libs.versions.toml
[versions]
kotlin = "1.7.10"
[libraries]
kotlin = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

**Version Catalogue**

versionCatalogs {

```
// would be nice to be able to define a version here and use them inside the toml files...
// val kotlin = "1.7.10"

create("tools") {
    from(files("gradle/tools.versions.toml"))
}

create("libs") {
    from(files("gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
}

// others...
```

}

**Question**

Is there a way to share a version definition in my setup and still keep the separate files? Doing all inside the `versionCatalogs` blog allows me to do this but only if I define everything there instead of the files...

I don't mind changing the `toml` files to `gradle.kts` files, but I could not find a way to merge multiple `gradle.kts` files - but maybe there's a way in this direction?

**Note**

I'm not looking for a different solution like `buildSrc` or composite builds, I'd like to use the gradle version catalogue.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is like below (I've tested on gradle 8.3, so API could be different)

1. tools.versions.toml

```
[versions]
kotlin = "1.7.10"
gradle = "7.2.1"
maven = "2.0"
```

2. libs.versions.toml

```
[libraries]
# ref version in tools.versions.toml
kotlin = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

3. settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  versionCatalogs {
    versions {
      from(files("tools.versions.toml")) // load versions
    }
    
    libs {
      // inject version info from versions
      def versionsCatalog = versions.build()
      
      versionsCatalog.getVersionAliases().forEach { alias ->
        // for debug - api could be diffent. check org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultVersionCatalog code 
        println("alias:" +alias +"/version:" +versionsCatalog.getVersion(alias).version.requiredVersion)

        // inject version to this catalog     
        version( alias, versionsCatalog.getVersion(alias).version.requiredVersion )
      }
      from(files("libs.versions.toml"))
    }  
}
```